# Convert JavaScript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to PHP and I'm trying to convert a simple Javascript function into a PHP function. I need help converting this code to PHP. thanks so much

```
var intArrayToHexString = function(arr) {
              var hex = "";
              for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] < 16)      
                hex += "0";
                hex += arr[i].toString(16);
              }
              return hex;
            };
```

PHP code: to php, this is what I've tried:

```
function intArrayToHexString($arr) {
              $hex = "";
              for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($arr); $i++) {
                if ($arr[$i] < 16)     
                $hex .= "0";
                $hex .= $arr[$i];
              }
              return $hex;
            };
```

PHP code does not work. Help me please.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"?

Comment: Can you print the output or anything..

Comment: `strlen` is a function for getting the length of a string, not the length of an array. I think you want `count`. Although you could just use a `foreach` loop instead of `for`.

Answer (score 0):

In php you use '.' to concatinate in stead of a '+'

$hex .= "0";
$hex .= $arr[$i];

Comment: thanks everyone, I need help processing this code  hex += arr[i].toString(16); convert it to php

Comment: try this way $hex .= "0";  $hex .= (string)$arr[$i];

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    function intArrayToHexString($arr) 
    {
             $hex = "";
             for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) 
             {
                    if ($arr[$i] < 16)     
                    $hex .= "0";
                    $hex .= base_convert($arr[$i],10, 16); // or dechex($arr[$i]);
             }
             return $hex;
   }
```